# I'm trying to periodically update a bar graph made with html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For my first foray into html5, I'm trying to make a scoreboard for the game Farkle.

I have figured out how to make a lame looking but functional graph system for up to five players, but I cannot figure out how to have it update without simply drawing over the old bar graphs.

I realize that my code could be much better, but I didn't want to write helper functions until I was sure how it would work.

I'm using buttons to trigger the "score"function for the appropriate player for now,
but I would like to be more automatic.

Here is a "working" version, so that you can see my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/dnsuj/1/

Comment: Can you place your example on jsfiddle, or post a fully working code snippet with the necessary JS and HTML?

Comment: Here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/kBJB4/

I did not about this site before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For graphical stuff, I organize my code into a setup() function, and a draw() function that gets called repeatedly, something like this:

```
function setup(){
    // set up variables you in draw, here
    // examples include initial document width and height, and things
    // like that (although those in particular would go in draw if you
    // want to handle the resize event.

    context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
}

function draw(){
    // clear the canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, docWidth, docHeight);

    // now redraw your bar graph
    // ...
}

setup();

setInterval("draw();", 60);
```

Do you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: I see the usefulness of it. If I can't get what I have working, I will definitely give that a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the basic of the periodic update:

```
function update() {
    score1();
    //you can add here everything you can write here loops, you can write here functions;
    move_to(100,100);
    alert('hello');
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
         j=2; //this is not needed, just to demonstrate you can do everything here
    }



    //this is the important, that call himself periodically again;
    window.setTimeout(100,update);
}
update();
```

this code calls an update function wich periodically calls himself. this is the best way to update something like canvas.

Comment: Would this allow me to change the positon of the box, rather than just drawing new ones over the old ones? that would be nice.

My main problem is that the boxes aren't behaiving at all, but this could be a nice feature. Thank you.

Comment: of course; all you should to that create a function that make all of the changes and call it inside of the function. for example create a function move_and_score(); this function includes all of the stuff needed for the update and then update. the main thing that the window.setTimeout function calls himself every 0.1 sec so it seems to be always updated. but you can change this.

Comment: I wish someone would have told me a long time ago.
Do you have any suggestions about how to fix my other problem?

Comment: create a new QUESTION and send me a link, i will try to give a solution.this is now offtopic. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869725/why-are-bar-graphs-acting-so-strangely-html5-canvas-and-javascript

Comment: @fehergeri I'm not sure that I understand your suggestion.
I fixed my other problems with the graphs, but I cannot your "update" thing to work.

I am trying to use the update function as the last command of the score function. Is that wrong?

Comment: edit: 
I call of my scorex() functions inside of update, and it calls them correctly, but it is still drawing new rectangles over the old ones.
http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/MUHjz/22/