# Why are bar graphs acting so strangely? html5 canvas, and javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, casting

For my first foray into html5, I'm trying to make a scoreboard for the game Farkle.

I have figured out how to make a lame looking but functional graph system for up to five players, but I cannot figure out how to have it update more than once.

I realize that my code could be much better, but I didn't want to write helper functions until I was sure how it would work.

As it is now, I'm getting weird behavior from the boxes. Rather than adding the "tally" to the total score, and drawing a box to reflect the new score, it does something that I don't understand. Try typing 10, and then 90 for the same player to see what I mean.

Here is a "working" version, so that you can see my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/kBJB4/

**edit:** It seems like it rather than adding the numbers normally, eg. 1+1=2, it is doing some kind of append thing, eg. 1+1=11. I have no idea why.

Comment: maybe it thinks you're using a `string` instead of an `integer`?  try using `parseInt(yourVariable)`

Comment: I just tried putting that in few places, and it did not help.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prompt()` function call returns a string. So the variable `tally` in the following statement

`var tally = prompt("score?");`

is actually a string. So applying `+` operator to a string operand and an integer operand results in treating both the operands as string and performing string concatenation instead of integer addition. A simple fix is to convert the return value of `prompt()` to integer like:

```
var tally = parseInt(prompt ("Score?"));
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update: @Suresh Kumar's answer is a bit cleaner. Leaving mine up though.*

Your code: `player1 += tally;` is treating both variables as `strings`.

Use `parseInt` to force it to use numbers:

```
player1 = parseInt(player1) + parseInt(tally);
```

Note: Trying to shortcut this with `player1 += parseInt(tally);` doesn't work, because it's still treating `player1` as a `string`

Comment: The unary `+` operator is more efficient and shorter on characters than `parseInt`. It also doesn't recognize octals (as is deprecated), though it does recognize hexadecimals. In short, I would recommend `(+player1) + (+tally)` instead of using `parseInt`.