# Having trouble updating html5 canvas correctly

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a simple demonstration of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/GqQBx/2/

I want the number in the box to increase by number that is typed in (for a farkle game).
It seems trivially simple, but I cannot get any method to work.
My current "update" function is from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868647/im-trying-to-periodically-update-a-bar-graph-made-with-html5-and-javascript)
Am I using it wrong?

My ultimate goal is to have the field to the right used as input, rather than a prompt, 
but that may be getting off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is only the initial update to the canvas. The update() function gets called, but only updates the var tally, doesnt update the canvas after that point.

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('tallyDisp');
var tally = 0;


function update() {
    tally += prompt("Update");
    window.setTimeout(100, update);
    if (elem && elem.getContext) {
        var context = elem.getContext('2d');
        if (context) {
            context.fillStyle = '#9f9';
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
            context.fillStyle = '#00f';
            context.font = 'bold 100px sans-serif';
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.textBaseline = 'middle';
            context.fillText(tally, 150, 100);
        }
    }
}
update();

//function ask() {
//    tally += parsInt(prompt("Ask"));
//            context.fillStyle = '#9f9'; 
//        context.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
//        context.fillStyle = '#00f';
//        context.font = 'italic 100px sans-serif';
//        context.textAlign = 'center';
//        context.textBaseline = 'middle';
//        context.fillText(tally, 150, 100);
//}
//ask();
```

Comment: Also, maybe change the line to:
tally += Numer(prompt("Update"));

Otherwise it will append it to the end of the string, instead of adding it to the total.

Comment: When I put the "Numer" line in, it doesn't give the prompt box anymore. Same thing with parsInt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good practice or not, but I've seen this before ...

`context.width = context.width; // Clears the canvas`